# android UI design using HTML

Tags: android

I designing the UI for android application using HTML in webView.But I am unable to get how to navigate to another page in  "anchor tag"
What link I give to navigate to another HTML page created in 'assets/www' folder.

Thanks...

Comment: This link may help you-http://blog.mailermailer.com/2011/11/anchor-tags-html-emails/

Comment: Are you trying to access it through javascript or through an <a> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.w);
    String link = "<a href=\"www.google.com\">www.google.com</a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><a name=\"link\"></a>Testing!";
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", link, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Dont forget to add **internet permission** in your manifest file.